# backbonejs demo case can't work well with localstorage added in stack snippet

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, code-snippets

I am trying to use the stack snippet tool to embed live demo case into my post. But I find when I add localstorage function into the demo case, it can't work well.
So I simplified my question to the basic backbone case, to emphasis the localstorage issue as above.
And if I remove the localstorage flow, the demo can run through very well, but if localstorage added, then it can't work well. The error message from console said 
`Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.`

Any idea?

```js
// A simple case

var Daymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 defaults : {
  day: 1,
 }
});

var DayCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Daymodel,
 localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("test-simple")
});


// The view for each day panel
var DayView = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName:"div",
 template: _.template( $('#eachday-template').html() ),
 initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
 }, 
 render: function(){
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  return this;
 }
});
// The view for the entire application
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#todoapp'),
  events: {
 "click #add-firebase":"addToLocalhost"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.daylist = this.$("#container"); // the daylist to append to
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
 this.collection.fetch();
  },

  addOne: function(todo) {
 var view = new DayView({model:todo});
    this.daylist.append(view.render().el);

  },
  addToLocalhost: function(){
 this.collection.create({
  day : this.collection.length + 1,
 });
  }

});

// Create a function to kick off our BackboneFire app
function init() {
  // The data we are syncing from our remote Firebase database
  var collection = new DayCollection();
  var app = new AppView({ collection: collection });
}
// When the document is ready, call the init function
$(function() {
  init();
});
```

```html
<div id="todoapp">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <button id="add-firebase">Add to Localstorage</button>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="eachday-template">
 <h3 class="which-day"> day <%= day %></h3>
    <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
</script> 
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.16/backbone.localStorage-min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message you're getting: **"The document is sandboxed"**. You can't mess with the localStorage as it's a restricted feature for all sandboxed `iframe` documents *unless* the restriction is specifically lifted.

If you look at the page source, you'll see the `iframe` and the `sandbox` attribute options.

```
<iframe name="d62428c9-4eba-3156-6ef7-8815d959a281" 
        sandbox="allow-modals allow-scripts" 
        class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0">
```

See [Play safely in sandboxed IFrames](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) for more details.

> The framed document is loaded into a unique origin, which means that
>   all same-origin checks will fail; unique origins match no other
>   origins ever, not even themselves. Among other impacts, this means
>   that **the document has no access to data stored in any origin's cookies
>   or any other storage mechanisms (DOM storage, Indexed DB, etc.)**.
>
> [...]
>
> With the exception of plugins, each of these restrictions can be
>   lifted by adding a flag to the sandbox attribute’s value. Sandboxed
>   documents can never run plugins, as plugins are unsandboxed native
>   code, but everything else is fair game:
>
> - **`allow-forms`** allows form submission.
> - **`allow-popups`** allows popups (`window.open()`, `showModalDialog()`, `target="_blank"`, etc.).
> - **`allow-pointer-lock`** allows (surprise!) pointer lock.
> - **`allow-same-origin`** allows the document to maintain its origin; pages loaded from `https://example.com/` will retain access to that
>     origin's data.
> - **`allow-scripts`** allows JavaScript execution, and also allows features to trigger automatically (as they'd be trivial to implement
>     via JavaScript).
> - **`allow-top-navigation`** allows the document to break out of the frame by navigating the top-level window.

For `allow-modals`, [*Add allow-modals to the sandbox of Stack Snippets*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297048/add-allow-modals-to-the-sandbox-of-stack-snippets-snippets-are-broken-in-chrome) gives more details:

> Chrome [blocks modal dialogs such as `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` in
>   sandboxed iframes unless `allow-modals` is set](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/mXX0AO6Lioo). This behavior became the
>   default as of [Chrome 46 and Opera 34](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4747009953103872).